# Changes in files on GitHub will also do change in GitLab files

Tags: git, github, gitlab, github-actions

I had multiple repositories on GitHub, now I shifted them to GitLab.

My developer commits changes on GitHub files.

Now, is there any solution that the changes committed on GitHub will also change files on GitLab?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/849308/7976758

Answer (score 0):

If, when "shifted", those repositories were pushed from a local GitHub copy to GitLab, they are sharing a common history.

That means, from your local GitLab clone, you can:

- add the old GitHub URL as a remote
- fetch from GitHub
- merge that fetched branch to your GitLab branch
- push to your normal origin remote (GitLab URL)

```sh
cd /path/to/GitLab/local/clone
git remote add github https://github.com/old/project
git fetch github
git merge github/main
git push
```

---

The other approach, as commented, would be for your developer to [push both to GitHub and GitLab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12795747/6309), assuming said developer is the only one working on the current branch in both repository (or it starts to involve complex synchronization steps before any push to both repositories)

```sh
# For developer working on GitHub
cd /path/to/GitHub/local/clone
git remote set-url origin --push --add https://github.com/old/project
git remote set-url origin --push --add https://gitlab.com/new/project
# work: add and commit
git push
```